# PyQt5 Open `QFontDialog` with the desired font

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is my font:

```
font = 'Algerian'
```

When I open `QFontDialog` I want the already selected font to appear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getFont() method (which I'm assuming you're using) allows you to set the initial font so the task is trivial:

```
initial_font = QtGui.QFont("Algerian") 
selected_font, ok = QtWidgets.QFontDialog.getFont(initial_font)
if ok:
    print(selected_font)
```